# Wordpress: Load specific CSS for admin user

Tags: wordpress, function

I want to work on my style.css file.
But It would be better if after all change and test I publish it for users.
So Is there any way to make another style.css which load just for admin user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the logged in user role before queuing it.
So the code should be like bellow.
you need to replace the **plugins_url( 'my-plugin/css/plugin.css' )** with your  stylesheet's path

```
function register_only_for_admin_styles() {
    if( current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') ) { 
        wp_register_style( 'admin-style', plugins_url( 'my-plugin/css/plugin.css' ) );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'admin-style' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_only_for_admin_styles' );
```

Try the code then let me know the result.
Thanks

Comment: thanks, man.
I edited it to
 `  wp_register_style( 'admin-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/my-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );`
and then it works.

Comment: but another problem appears! When I disable some CSS from my-admin-style, it comes back, because the main style loads too. @souvik-sikdar

Comment: Do you want to load the admin-style only for admins?